# iOS camera permissions, native iOS permission alert not firing on first request

Tags: android, ios, react-native, permissions, ios-camera

Hi all I have an app with a feature that allows the user to take a picture during a task.

Recently when asking for camera permissions for the first time the device is not showing the native alert but rather deferring to my secondary alert that is supposed to be used if the user had denied or changed their permissions settings after the first attempt.

My understanding is that when a device is asked for the first time iOS will supply the permissions alert similar to this

[image]

I have this in my `info.plist`

```
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow access to your camera to take pictures of your dog!</string>
```

code when the user taps the camera button in app (solution at bottom)

```
  function takePhoto() {
    check(
      Platform.select({
        ios: PERMISSIONS.IOS.CAMERA,
        android: PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.CAMERA,
      })
    )
      .then(async (response) => {
        if (response == 'unavailable') {
          alert('Camera is not available on this device');
          return;
        }

        const userId = auth().currentUser.uid;

        let image = null;
        const mapAPI = new MapAPI(firestore(), userId, storage);

        const showSettingsAlert = (title, message) => {
          Alert.alert(
            title,
            message,
            [
              {
                text: translations['settings.goto'],
                onPress: async () => {
                  Linking.openSettings();
                },
              },
              {
                text: translations['cancel'],
                onPress: () => {
                  console.log('Cancel Pressed');
                },
                style: 'cancel',
              },
            ],
            { cancelable: true }
          );
        };

        if (response != RESULTS.GRANTED) {
          showSettingsAlert(
            translations['permissions.cameratitle'],
            translations['permissions.cameradesc']
          );
          return;
        }
```

I've been trying to tackle this for a while and appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I realized with the help from another overflower that I had not requested to access the camera before calling the custom alert.

Here is the solution that worked in my instance.

```
  const takePhoto = async () => {
    const imageProps = {
      mediaType: 'photo',
      width: 400,
      height: 400,
      writeTempFile: true,
    };

    const userId = auth().currentUser.uid;

    let image = null;
    const mapAPI = new MapAPI(firestore(), userId, storage);

    try {
      image = await ImageCropPicker.openCamera(imageProps);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);

      const response = await check(
        Platform.select({
          ios: PERMISSIONS.IOS.CAMERA,
          android: PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.CAMERA,
        })
      );
      if (response !== RESULTS.GRANTED && response !== RESULTS.UNAVAILABLE) {
        showSettingsAlert(
          translations['permissions.cameratitle'],
          translations['permissions.cameradesc']
        );
      }
    }

    if (!image) {
      return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are testing for `response != RESULTS.GRANTED`. So, if it is “not determined” (the status prior to asking the user’s permissions), that would result in your alert. We generally show our custom alert if the status is “denied” or “restricted”, rather than not “granted”.

Comment: Hey @Rob thanks for the response and it makes sense but even with `response != RESULTS.GRANTED` it still checks all other instances and if the result was “not determined” I would expect iOS to present the default alert. Either way even as a new user on a new device iOS is not giving that option and when I log `response` it is returning denied even though I was not given the chance to deny it initially. Lastly even when using the custom alert it takes me to the app settings but does not present a camera option. Hope all that is clear and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: To get the system auth dialog you have to either request it manually, or try to just use camera. See [Requesting Authorization for Media Capture on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/requesting_authorization_for_media_capture_on_ios) for the standard flow. But until you do this, settings won’t even show the camera auth controls. And your above code doesn’t request any permission, so it’s hitting that `if` statement while the auth status is still “not determined” and because that also happens to not equal “granted”, you’re showing your alert.

Comment: yes, I didn't realize I hadn't requested to actually use the camera, ooof! I added the solution above

Comment: thanks you for pointing that out, very much appreciated. Thanks for the help/communication.